# Keras + Tensorflow optimization stalls

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I installed Theano (TH), Tensorflow (TF) and Keras.
Basic testing seem to indicate that they work with the GPU (GTX 1070), Cuda 8.0, cuDNN5.1 .

If I run the cifar10_cnn.py [Keras example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py) with TH as backend, it seems to work ok, taking ~18s/epoch.
If I run it with TF then,*almost* all the times (it has worked occasionally, can't reproduce it), the optimization stalls with acc=0.1 after *every* epoch. It is as if weights were not updated.

This is a shame because TF backend was taking ~10s/epoch (even the very few times it worked). I'm using Conda and I am very new to Python. If that helps, "conda list" seems to show two versions for some of the packages.

If you have any clues, please let me know. Thanks. Screenshot below :

```
python cifar10_cnn.py

Using TensorFlow backend.

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally

X_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)

50000 train samples

10000 test samples

Using real-time data augmentation.

Epoch 1/200

I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 

name: GeForce GTX 1070

major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7845

pciBusID 0000:01:00.0

Total memory: 7.92GiB

Free memory: 7.60GiB

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)

50000/50000 [==============================] - 11s - loss: 2.3029 - acc: 0.0999 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000

Epoch 2/200

50000/50000 [==============================] - 10s - loss: 2.3028 - acc: 0.0980 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000

Epoch 3/200

50000/50000 [==============================] - 10s - loss: 2.3028 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000

Epoch 4/200

50000/50000 [==============================] - 10s - loss: 2.3028 - acc: 0.0980 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_acc: 0.1000

Epoch 5/200

13184/50000 [======>.......................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 2.3026 - acc: 0.1044^CTraceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look to me like it is just random guessing since there are 10 possibilities and it is right 10% of the time.  The only thing I can think of is that you learning rate is a bit too high.  I have seen with a high learning rate models will sometimes converge and sometimes not converge.  On the backend right now I think theano performs more optimizations so maybe this is slightly affecting something.  Try lowering the learning rate by a factor of 10 and see if it converges.

Comment: Thank you, I lowered the learning rate to 0.001 and it seems to have worked. I assumed that an example on GitHub would have worked "out of the box", but maybe it was only tested on TH. Again, thanks.