# keras stuck during optimization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

After trying the Keras example on CIFAR10, I decided to go for something bigger : a VGG-like net on the [Tiny Imagenet](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/tiny-imagenet-200.zip) dataset. This is a subset of the ImageNet dataset with 200 classes (instead of 1000) and 100K images downscaled to 64x64.

I got the VGG-like model from the file vgg_like_convnet.py [here](https://github.com/annashcherbina/cs231n_project). Unfortunately, things are going pretty much like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993601/keras-tensorflow-optimization-stalls) except that this time changing the learning rate or swapping TH for TF does not help. Neither changing the optimizer (see code below).

Accuracy is basically stuck at 0.005 which, as it was pointed out, is what you would expected for completely random answer with 200 classes. Worse, if, by a fluke of weights init, it starts at, say, 0.007, it will quickly converges to 0.005 and firmly stays there for any subsequent epoch.

The Keras code (TH version) is below :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.regularizers import l2, activity_l2, l1, activity_l1
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, Adagrad, Adadelta
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np
import cPickle as pickle

# seed = 7
# np.random.seed(seed)

batch_size = 64
nb_classes = 200
nb_epoch = 30

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 64, 64
# the tiny image net images are RGB
img_channels = 3

# Load the train dataset for TH
print('Load training data')
X_train=pickle.load(open('xtrain_shu_th.p','rb')) # np.zeros((100000,3,64,64)).astype('uint8')
y_train=pickle.load(open('ytrain_shu_th.p','rb')) # np.zeros((100000,1)).astype('uint8')

# Load the test dataset for TH
print('Load validation data')
X_test=pickle.load(open('xtest_th.p','rb')) # np.zeros((10000,3,64,64)).astype('uint8')
y_test=pickle.load(open('ytest_th.p','rb')) # np.zeros((10000,1)).astype('uint8')

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
# (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(3,64,64)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu',))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))#,weights=pretrained_weights['layer_6'].values()))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))#,weights=pretrained_weights['layer_8'].values()))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))#,weights=pretrained_weights['layer_11'].values()))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))#,weights=pretrained_weights['layer_13'].values()))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))#,weights=pretrained_weights['layer_15'].values()))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))#,weights=pretrained_weights['layer_18'].values()))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))#,weights=pretrained_weights['layer_20'].values()))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))#,weights=pretrained_weights['layer_22'].values()))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='softmax'))

# let's train the model using SGD + momentum (how original).

opt = SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.7, nesterov=True)
# opt= Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
# opt = Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
# opt = Adagrad(lr=0.01, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

print('Optimization....')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
          shuffle=True)

# Save the resulting model
model.save('model.h5')
```

The Tiny Imagenet dataset consists of JPEG images that I converted to PPM with djpeg. I then created a large binary file containing, for each image, the class label (1 byte) followed by (64x64x3 bytes).

Reading this file from Keras was excruciatingly slow. So (I'm very new to Python, it might sound dumb to you), I decided to init a 4D Numpy array (100000,3,64,64) (for TH, (100000,64,64,3) for TF) with the dataset and pickle it. It now takes ~40s to load the dataset in the array when I run the code above.

I even checked that the pickled array contained the data in the right order with the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import cPickle as pickle

print("Reading data")
pix=pickle.load(open('xtrain_th.p','rb'))
print("Done")

img=67857

f=open('img'+str(img)+'.ppm','wb')
f.write('P6\n64 64\n255\n')

for y in range(0,64):
    for x in range(0,64):
        f.write(chr(pix[img][0][y][x]))
        f.write(chr(pix[img][1][y][x]))
        f.write(chr(pix[img][2][y][x]))
f.close()
```

This extracts PPM images back from the dataset.

Finally, I noticed that the training dataset was too ordered (i.e. the first 500 images all belonged to class 0, the second 500 to class 1, etc. etc.)

So I shuffled them with the code below:

```
# Dataset preparation for Theano backend
import cPickle as pickle
import numpy as np
import random as rnd

n=100000

print('Load training data')
X_train=pickle.load(open('xtrain_th.p','rb')) # np.zeros((100000,3,64,64)).astype('uint8')
y_train=pickle.load(open('ytrain_th.p','rb')) # np.zeros((100000,1)).astype('uint8')

tmpa=np.zeros((3,64,64)).astype('uint8')

# Shuffle the data
print('Shuffling training data')
for _ in range(0,n):
    i=rnd.randrange(n)
    j=rnd.randrange(n)
    tmpa=X_train[i]
    X_train[i]=X_train[j];
    X_train[j]=tmpa
    tmp=y_train[i][0]
    y_train[i][0]=y_train[j][0]
    y_train[j][0]=tmp

print 'Pickle dump'
pickle.dump(X_train,open('xtrain_shu_th.p','wb'))
pickle.dump(y_train,open('ytrain_shu_th.p','wb'))
```

Nothing helped. I wasn't expecting 99% accuracy at the first attempt, but at least some movement and then plateau.

I wanted to try TFLearn, but it had a pending bug when I looked a few days ago.

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I actually can see a problem in the Keras code : starting from an image as small a 64x64, the maxpools get it down to almost nothing before it gets to the dense layers.........

Comment: I took the network from the file vgg16_keras.py, not vgg_like_convnet.py. The latter has 5 stages of maxpools each reducing the resolution by 2 on each side. Since the image resolution starts at 64x64, it reaches only 2x2 before the dense layers. This seems way too small. So I cut a couple of maxpool layers and thinned the network. Now the layer before the dense ones is 8x8 (similar to 7x7 in VGG) but it made no difference : stuck at 0.005 accuracy. Changing the optimizer makes a difference in the starting point, but, eventually, the result is exactly the same : 5.298 and acc=1/200

Comment: Are you sure that your training data matches. I.E the right label for the right img. Is the image in the right format. I.E can you plot it? Normally these or the optimizer are problems with incredibly bad accuracy.

Comment: Yes, I thought about mislabeling. I modified the program above that reads the pre-shuffled dataset to also read and print the label as well as generating the PPM image. I then visually checked that it matched the same image.and label in the original dataset for a few data points. Not conclusive, but something. As for plotting, I don't know how to do it, I need to look into it. I will start now from a minimalist net and then try to grow it.

Comment: Made a minimalist net (i.e. identical to the CIFAR10 Keras example but with 200 outputs) and same exact problem. Maybe a bit of oscillation around 0.005. I have absolutely no idea and my best guess is something worng wiht the dataset but no idea what

Comment: The labels of the shuffled dataset seem to be wrong. Can anyone spot any problems in the shuffle program above ? It is supposed to swap two random elements of the  dataset and their labels 100,000 times. I can see an extra ';' that doesn't belong. However, even eliminating the extra ';', there is still a mismatch between images and labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the build in shuffle of the keras model API (https://keras.io/models/model/#fit). Just set the shuffle parameter to true. You can do both batch shuffle and global shuffle. The default is global shuffle.

One thing to note though is that the validation split in fit is done before the shuffling takes place. Therefore in case you want to shuffle your validation data too I would advise you to use: `sklearn.utils.shuffle`. (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html)

From github:

```
if shuffle == 'batch':
    index_array = batch_shuffle(index_array, batch_size)              
elif shuffle:
    random.shuffle(index_array)
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw that in Keras doc, but will it shuffle the whole dataset or only within a batch ? Keras doc is very scant and not very clear on this. The unshuffled dataset is VERY ordered : 200 sets of 500 images belonging to the same class. Since a batch is only 32/64, shuffling within a batch will be useless. Shuffle need s to be global.

Comment: Edited answer to address follow up question.

Comment: Thank you, Using the unshuffled dataset and letting Keras shuffle it is working on the minimalist net. It moved slowly but surely and after 200 epochs it was still making progress, albeit still only at 20% accuracy which is a LOT better than 0.5%!

Comment: You can thank me by accepting the answer and/or upvoting.

Comment: I clicked the up arrow near your answer and it said that, since I have no reputation (or something like that), my endorsement was noted but not counted. Is there anything else I can do ? How do I accept an answer ?